# asp.net file merge which is done by different developers

Tags: .net, version-control, merge, checkin

we are developing some ASP.NET project, in that we work on same file. so we find difficulty to merger after the modifications. can you please give me a solution for this in detail.

thanks in advance.

Comment: This is exactly what Source control systems are for. Maybe look into using Team Foundation server or Subversion.

Comment: move the logic from the aspx file to services and/or business object.

Comment: @Jakub: Why not? He's having difficulty merging the work of several developers, and he's asking for help or suggestions.

Comment: @user change the [version-control] tag to whatever version control system you are actually using (unless you aren't).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [Source Version Control system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control)

Answer (score 0):

When working with many members on the same Project, there are Tools like Team Foundation Server, Source Safe, Subversion etc.

Check Wikipedia for a overview http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revision_control

And as you work with ASP.NET i would focus on a Microsoft Product like Team Foundation Server or Source Safe as the integrate well with Visual Studio.

Comment: Don't recommend people Source Safe in 2011

Answer (score 0):

You probably need some sort of Source Control system. Visual Studio doesn't provide one out-of-the-box, but there are plenty of free solutions. The most popular ones at the moment are subversion, git, and mercurial; from what you tell us, I would assume git or mercurial would be the best fit, since they do not require a server.